# Get certain values in a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have this NSString below. I want to be able to get the name of each application and the location of it. Can someone help me or point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

```
Applications:

Xcode:

  Version: 4.5.2
  Last Modified: 11/3/12 11:45 PM
  Kind: Intel
  64-Bit (Intel): Yes
  App Store: Yes
  Location: /Applications/Xcode.app

Terminal:

  Version: 2.3
  Last Modified: 6/21/12 12:01 AM
  Kind: Intel
  64-Bit (Intel): Yes
  App Store: No
  Location: /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app

Google Chrome:

  Version: 23.0.1271.64
  Last Modified: 10/31/12 7:59 PM
  Kind: Intel
  64-Bit (Intel): No
  App Store: No
  Location: /Applications/Google Chrome.app

App Store:

  Version: 1.2.1
  Last Modified: 4/18/12 7:52 PM
  Kind: Intel
  64-Bit (Intel): Yes
  App Store: No
  Location: /Applications/App Store.app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use componentsSeparatedByString if there are easy delimiters. If not, try to use a regex with NSRegularExpression to find the value

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of NSScanner using your string. Since instances of NSScanner default to skipping whitespace and newlines by default, you need to disable this behavior before proceeding, like this:

```
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[[[NSCharacterSet alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

From here, you'd do something like this:

```
NSString *appName = nil;

[scanner scanString:@"Applications:" intoString:NULL];

NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];

[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:NULL];

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO)
{
    // Get your application name.
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:&appName];
    [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:NULL];

    // You could do something with your application name here.

    // Skip over the other stuff.
    for (NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < 6; idx++)
    {
        [scanner scanUpToString:@":" intoString:NULL];
        [scanner scanString:@":" intoString:NULL];
        [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:NULL];
        [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:NULL];
    }
}
```

Note that, despite appearances, I didn't give you a complete solution. Beyond checking for the end of the string, there's no error checking, and it goes without saying that Real Applications check for errors. (There should even have been a check for end-of-string at the very outset.) Also, this snippet relies on a rigid presentation of the data, such as you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to solve this.  `NSRegularExpression` has been mentioned.  `NSScanner` is another.  Here's a potential solution (no guarantees about correctness - just a guide.)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *source = @"Applications:\n\nXcode:\n\n  Version: 4.5.\n  Last Modified: 11/3/12 11:45 PM\n  Kind: Intel\n  64-Bit (Intel): Yes\n App Store: Yes\n  Location: /Applications/Xcode.app";
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:source];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@":" intoString:NULL];
        [scanner scanString:@":" intoString:NULL];

        while( ![scanner isAtEnd] ) {
            NSString *appName = nil;
            NSString *appPath = nil;

            [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] intoString:NULL];
            [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] intoString:&appName];

            NSString *junk = nil;
            [scanner scanUpToString:@"Location: " intoString:&junk];
            [scanner scanString:@"Location: " intoString:NULL];
            [scanner scanUpToString:@"\n" intoString:&appPath];
            [scanner scanString:@"\n" intoString:NULL];

            printf("app name = %s, path = %s\n",[appName UTF8String],[appPath UTF8String]);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```